# How can I mine efficiently with the Assessor?

Tags: dome-keeper

I recently booted up Dome Keeper for the first time since the Assessor was released, and it's giving me quite a bit of trouble. It's drastically different than the Engineer, and I find I'm struggling to mine efficiently. In small spaces the Assessor is really efficient, but once I've cleared out an area of ~5 tiles, it slows down a lot, with my orbs taking a while to break anything. The end result of all this is I can't keep up with the scaling waves, and I get wiped out fairly quickly.

I can only assume I'm missing something about the Assessor.

**How can I efficiently gather resources with the Assessor?**